# laravel sail - Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.14

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Similar/same as:
[Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72846653/your-composer-dependencies-require-a-php-version-8-1-0)

I'm using wsl.
I've installed php8.1 using

```
sudo apt install php8.1 libapache2-mod-php8.1
```

...and I've uninstalled all versions of php except for 8.1 using:

`sudo apt remove php8.0`

...etc. I've then run:

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar8.1
update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar8.1
service apache2 restart
```

...and I've restarted wsl and yet, when I attempt to start sail:

```
./vendor/bin/sail up
```

I'm still getting the error:

```
Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.14.
```

Now then,

```
php -v
```

gives:

```
PHP 8.1.8 (cli) (built: Jul 11 2022 08:29:57) (NTS)
```

...and I've absolutely no idea where

```
You are running 8.0.14.
```

...is coming from! I think I've tried everything I can find to resolve this (except for overriding composer platform requirements - but something I'm using is expecting php8.1, so I don't really want to change it!)

Any help greatly appreciated

A.

Comment: It might be same problem as is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71081381/laravel-sail-installing-wrong-php-version). Did you try to update Sail? It [has been fixed](https://github.com/laravel/sail/commit/dbe4a908d254d91f99ed89047c9eec4bae8973b0) since Jan 20.

Comment: `./vendor/bin/sail up` uses the docker-compose file, how does yours look?

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep php8` tell you? Maybe there are more PHP 8.0 packages installed?

Comment: Ah! Right, ok, so I'm thick! I updated docker-compose.yml so that:
```
context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
```
and
```
image: sail-8.1/app
```
...which appears to have solved the PHP error.
However, I cannot access my app at localhost (I get the apache default page)

Where do I go next?!

Comment: That depends. Why do you use `apt`  when running stuff in a Docker container? Why not properly update that container instead?

Comment: yeh, cos I'm stupid - I was doing apt remove on local, not docker!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jax-p for pointing me in the right direction and [this helpful article](https://dev.to/devtonight/how-to-update-laravel-sail-to-php-v81-3nhe)!:

I updated docker-compose.yml so that:

```
context: ./vendor/laravel/sail/runtimes/8.1
```

and

```
image: sail-8.1/app
```

then ran:

```
./vendor/bin/sail build --no-cache
```

...which appears to have solved the PHP error.